# Local storage for a browser plugin that isnt dependant on the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, local-storage

So im writing a browser plugin that needs to store data locally.
I'm using the jQuery jStorage plugin so my code looks something like this:

```
var value = ($.jStorage.get("test")) + 1 ;
$.jStorage.set("test", value);
console.log($.jStorage.get("test"));
```

Problem is that it stores the value specifically to the website you're on. So if the plugin activates on example1.com, the value could be 10;
then if it activates on example2.com the value could be totally different;

I need to store data locally that will remain the same on all pages.
Either by storing it in the browser plugins storage or something(not so ideal as that means for each browser i'd have to figure it out again i assume.)

But any help or direction would be AWESOME!

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage feature of jquery. Refer following example

Assign value to variable

```
localStorage["sample"] = 1;
```

Get value from local storage

```
var mySample = localStorage["sample"];
```

Jquery will store local variable in browser so you will get even after refreshing page.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Overlayed an invisible iFrame that was held on my server. Using the iframe i could save data on the localhost and pull it out when needed via the plugin.